# How do I set 0 for total length except the number exist in row in MySql

Tags: mysql

The filed length is varchar(7) I just want to set 0 before the ID number, for all rows as below:

```
TraineeID       TraineeID
   74            0000074
 1290            0001290
51315            0051315
```

Please help.

Regards
Mir

Comment: Use can use the format() function in mysql scripts and keep data saved as int. Not sure please describe better

Comment: If you don't want to alter the data within the database, then you could look into padding the zeros in the programming language using the data. For example in php: `sprintf("%07d", $row['TraineeID']);`

Comment: @DrewPierce, I need to print it as same format or search with 7 character, Is there still way to keep it as int?

Comment: Yes there is. Please keep the int tho first and foremost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [**LPAD**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad):

```
SELECT LPAD(TraineeID,7,'0');
```

Comment: I need to update all existing number in `tbl_assigned` in column 'TraineeID'. could you tell please where I put the table name.

Comment: Mir these are basic questions can u go thru a basic tutorial online please

Comment: @MirAbzalAli You should check the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)